# XML get value of td cell using XPath expression

Tags: c#, xpath, xml-parsing

Im attempting to get td cell values within a table cell without a name/id from a table row using an XPath expression but haven't been able to resolve it. Could readers let me know where Im wrong?

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load("C:\\trial.html");

    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");

    XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    System.Xml.XmlNodeList rowNodes = root.SelectNodes(@"ns:body/ns:div[@id='Index']/ns:div[@class='container']/ns:div[@class='maintext']/ns:table[@class='a_table']/ns:tr[@class='a_table_row']", nsmgr);

    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in rowNodes)
    {
        // Is there a way to get nodes with td values(non-empty)? My attempts
        // seem to be wrong
        //System.Xml.XmlNodeList tds = xmlNode.SelectNodes("//td[text()]", nsmgr);
        //System.Xml.XmlNodeList tds = xmlNode.SelectNodes("//td[contains(text(), .)]", nsmgr);
        if (xmlNode.ChildNodes.Count == 3)
            nodes.Add(xmlNode);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code I think you want to use

```
XmlNodeList tds = xmlNode.SelectNodes("ns:td[normalize-space()]", nsmgr);
```

to find any non-empty `td` child elements of the `tr` selected as `xmlNode`.